# Django model form with additional parameters will not validate

Tags: python, django, forms

I have looked at the over-dozen SO threads on django validation forms but have not been able to figure out why my form will neither validate nor output any errors.

The form is generated off a model and is loaded with two custom parameters `item` and `size_choices`.

I presume that somehow my form initiation is faulty? I also thought that maybe it's because I make a form on only a subset of the model fields but don't fill all of the model fields out yet, according to django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/), that shouldn't be an issue since only included fields get validated.

Here are the simplified model, form, view, and template codes:

the model:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    # item description
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    itemSizes = [(s,s.upper()) for s in  ['xxs','xs','s','m','l','xl','xxl','xxxl','count']]
    size = models.CharField("Item size", max_length = 5, choices = itemSizes)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    
    class Recipient(models.TextChoices):
        TEAM = 'TEAM MEMBER'
        RETAIL = 'RETAIL'

    recipient = models.CharField(max_length=11, choices = Recipient.choices, default=Recipient.RETAIL)
    date = models.DateField('date of order',auto_now_add=True)
```

the form:

```
class itemOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,size_choices = None,item=None ,*args,**kwargs):                  
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs) #itemOrderForm,self
        if size_choices:
            self.fields['size'].choices = size_choices
            self.fields['item'].initial = item
            #self.fields['item'].disabled=True
            #print("GOT HERE")
 
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('item','size', 'quantity')
```

the view:

```
def orderCart(request):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = itemOrderForm(request.POST)
        print(form.is_valid()) 
        print(form.errors) #this doesn't print anything 
        if form.is_valid():
            print("VALID!!!")
    item = Item.objects.all()[0]    
    context['form'] = itemOrderForm(size_choices =[('s','S'),('m','M')],item=item)
    return render(request, 'inv_check/ordercart.html', context)
```

the template:

```
{% extends 'inv_check/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">      
    <form method="post" >
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_table }}
        <td><input type="submit" value="Add to cart"/></td>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Which field validation is missing?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I am not sure what you mean.All i know is that, for some reason, the `print(form.is_valid())` returns `False` after `form = itemOrderForm(request.POST)`

Comment: and what is the output of `print(form.errors)` I don't think it can be empty if the form is *invalid*

Comment: @ArakkalAbu it prints a blank line and no text

Comment: One side note is that trying to submit a form with a disabled field (ie item in my case) will fail if the field is required, which in my case, it is. However, removing that line still cannot validate the form

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of tinkering, it seems Django's form validator does not like keyword arguments being passed to form `def __init__ ()`, so the attempt to pass `size_choices` and `item` to `def __init__ (self,size_choices,item...)` may have been the culprit.

The best way to pass arguments remains to be `**kwargs`. The ensuing modification to `def __init__ ()...` got the same results and can pass Django's form validation.

Form:

```
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs): #size_choices=None,max_quant=100,  
        size_choices = kwargs.pop('size_choices',None)
        max_quant = kwargs.pop('max_quant',None)
        item = kwargs.pop('item', None)
        super(itemOrderForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs) #itemOrderForm,self
        
        if size_choices:
            self.fields['item'].choices = [(s,s) for s in [item]]
            self.fields['size'].choices = size_choices
            #self.fields['quantity'].choices = [(i+1,i+1) for i in range(max_quant)]
```

view

```
context['form'] = itemOrderForm(size_choices = sizeChoices,max_quant = max_quant, item=item)
```